# Spring mvc messagesource failed in annotation

Tags: spring, annotations

I am able to retrieve message with this code

```
public class UserApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext appContext 
        = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-configuration.xml");

    System.out.println(appContext.getMessage("NotEmpty.userForm.name", 
            new Object[] { 28,"http://www.mkyong.com" }, Locale.US ));

    }
}
```

But failed with the same application-configuration.xml using ContextConfiguration Annotation. it is showing me

Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'NotEmpty.userForm.name' for locale 'en_US'.

```
@Controller
@ContextConfiguration("/application-configuration.xml")
public class UserController {
    private static final Logger logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAddUserForm(Model model) {

        String temp = appContext.getMessage("NotEmpty.userForm.name", 
            new Object[] { 28,"http://www.mkyong.com" }, Locale.US ));
    }
}
```

application-configuration.xml

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename">            
            <beans:value>locale/messages</beans:value>          
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Did i use the wrong annotation for this?

Comment: where is ur xml config file? same directory as UserController? Maybe u the / in the beginning.

Comment: xml config file is located under src/main/resources . i did try to remove that / in the begining. it still doesn't work and giving same NoSuchMessageException